# AWS Customized AMI - number of running instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I have created a public customized AMI. Is there any way to know how many instances have been launched from my public customized AMI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any way from AWS side to find that. What you can do is customize a Sendmail in your AMI which will email you when some body launches the instance using your public AMI.